# TypeError: cognitiveServices.face is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using [Microsoft Cognitive Services](https://github.com/joshbalfour/node-cognitive-services#face---detect) api for nodejs. I have following code

```
const cognitiveServices = require('cognitive-services');

const face = new cognitiveServices.face({
    API_KEY: yourApiKey
})

const parameters = {
    returnFaceId: "true"
    returnFaceLandmarks: "false"
};
const body = {
    "url": "URL of input image"
};


face.detect({
    parameters,
    body
})
.then((response) => {
      console.log('Got response', response);
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.error('Encountered error making request:', err);
});
```

however, when I execute this code I get following error

```
const face = new cognitiveServices.face({
               ^

TypeError: cognitiveServices.face is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/..../face.js:3:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:590:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: You have a require statement at the top of that module, right? Can you edit your question to include that statement? Likewise it'd be good to verify that you correctly installed the cognitive services api per the Installation and Getting Started steps at https://github.com/joshbalfour/node-cognitive-services#installation.

Comment: Yes I have that and I updated my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the documentation for the `cognitive-services` module is incorrect: you need to call `cognitiveServices.face(...)` without `new`.

If you look at https://github.com/joshbalfour/node-cognitive-services/blob/master/api/face.js, you can see that `face` is defined as an arrow function, which makes it not a constructor. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37037600/483595 for details on why that is the case.

Edit: looks like the issue is already reported here: https://github.com/joshbalfour/node-cognitive-services/issues/2