# Javascript constructor from string variable in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I've got a little angular (v1.5.11) app where I'm trying to instantiate an object from a string variable. This code used to work in my old setup but after changing from bower/gulp to webpack (3.8.1), I'm now getting the error below. I'm not sure whether this is caused by my new import statement or something.

A similar question ([Javascript "Not a Constructor" Exception while creating objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107198/javascript-not-a-constructor-exception-while-creating-objects)) dicussed the problem but I wasn't able to get get any of the solutions to work in my example which is why I'm thinking it might be down to the import or the pojo structure itself?

**Error:**

```
TypeError: $window[iteratorType] is not a constructor
```

**Code:**

*MyService.js*

```
import ListIterator from './util/listiterator.pojo.js';

MyService.$inject = ['$log', '$window'];

function MyService($log, $window) {
  ...
  // this variable is obviously dynamic but for now I made it a static string
  var iteratorType = 'ListIterator';
  var iterator = new $window[iteratorType](); //<-- breaks as $window[iteratorType] is undefined
  //var iterator = new ListIterator();  <-- this works just fine
  ...
```

*listiterator.pojo.js*

```
var ListIterator = function() {
    this.executedIterations = 0;
    this.iter = null;
};
...
export default ListIterator;
```

Comment: You are importing `ListIterator` class in `MyService` file. Why don't you use this `ListIterator` class directly?

Comment: I've added an edit explaining that the answers in this question didn't help me solve my issue.

Comment: You used global function before. And switched to import. It's no longer available on window. And you already stated that `var iterator = new ListIterator()` works fine. It's unclear what the problem is.

Comment: @estus The line: var iterator = new $window[iteratorType](); doesn't work and creates the error above. The line after that is just to show that the function is available in general.

Comment: So what is the question exactly?

Comment: How can I fix the error so this line `var iterator = new $window[iteratorType]();` works?

Comment: You can either expose functions you need to use there as globals like `window.ListIterator = ListIterator` (which doesn't look good), or switch from globals to idiomatic Angular alternatives, as one of the answer suggests.

Comment: Got it, my confusion came from the fact that I thought ListIterator was already globally available. But I had to add `window.ListIterator = ListIterator;` after my import. At least I understand why now and can look for a better option (e.g. angular injection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is angular way:

```
app.factory('F1', function() {...})
app.factory('F2', function() {...})
app.factory('F3', function() {...})

app.factory('MyService', function($injector) {
  var name = 'F1';
  var someFactory = $injector.get(name);
})
```

Comment: I'm not injecting an angular service, but just like to use a javascript constructor available in the global scope.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the correct answer as it's a nicer way to rewrite my code.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change any of your code, you could tell webpack to provide your service. This will make it available under window scope:

```
rules: [{
    test: require.resolve('./util/listiterator.pojo.js'), //the correct absolute path
    use: [{
        loader: 'expose-loader',
        options: 'ListIterator'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This is untested with your example, but works fine in my setup with *Highcharts* and *AngularJS*.

**EDIT**

You have to install `npm i -D expose-loader` of course.

Comment: I'm fine with changing my code which is why I added the import statement that should basically end up doing the same just more local to this service in my opinion.