# The beginners' error in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm a beginner in TypeScript and wrote the following code in MVC5 application:

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

View:

```html
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="cont"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

TypeScript:

```
class MyClass {
    public render(divId: string, text: string) {
        var el: HTMLElement = document.getElementById(divId);
        el.innerText = text;
    }
}

window.onload = () => {
    var MyClass = new MyClass();
    MyClass.render("cont", "Hello World");
};
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es6",    
        "outDir": "../Scripts"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "wwwroot"
    ]
}
```

I've got the following error:

> TypeError: MyClass is not a constructor.

How can I run my first TypeScript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript "Not a Constructor" Exception while creating objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107198/javascript-not-a-constructor-exception-while-creating-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the same name for the class and the variable, as that will mean in the `onload` function context `MyClass` will refer to the variable not the class.

If you hover over the `MyClass` in `new MyClass()` you will see the tooltip tell you it is referring to the variable not the class. The reason the compiler did not catch this is that `MyClass` is implicitly typed to `any` so it can be a constructor. If you would have used `let` or `const` you would have gotten an error, also if you had used the `noImplicitAny` option.

Comment: I use VS2013 and put "let" instead of "var", but there's no compiler error.

Comment: That is strange, on version 2.6.2 with no options specified, I get `error TS2448: Block-scoped variable 'MyClass' used before its declaration`

Comment: No. You're right. The error comes up in compile time. I've made mistake by putting "let" in class only, but not in calling code. When I put "let" in calling code as well, the compiler error has been appeared.